# Why don't the Colonial and Okkar factions attack each other in EVERSPACE?

Tags: everspace

If I hang around in a zone for too long, I start to get warnings that Okkar forces are inbound. These usually start with some manageable fighters and drones, but eventually, Okkar Corvettes spawn in. With the correct setup, I can take down one of these before the fighting gets too intense. After a short time, Colonial warships will also warp in. I know I can't kill these, as I've read the developers comments on such, but I am wondering why they all gang up on me.

G&B will fight against Okkar or Outlaw fighters, but it seems like the Okkar and Colonial ships will not engage each other, and only focus on me. I've tried reading through the lore that I've collected to see if there's an alliance between those factions, but so far I haven't found anything as such, so:

**Why don't the Colonial Warships and Okkar forces attack each other?**